# "Permission denied" error on .sh script on RHEL5

Tags: shell, permissions, redhat, java

```
root@server [/mnt/elm332/Setup/Linux]# ./setupLinux64.sh -c
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
./setupLinux64.sh: line 433: /tmp/setupLinux64.sh.28603.dir/jre/bin/java: Permission denied

root@server [/mnt/elm332/Setup/Linux]# whoami
root
```

Why would this be happening? Note that this is a mounted ISO file (copied in /tmp), and the permissions on that are:

```
 -rw-r--r--  1 root   root   554434560 Aug 26 16:05 elm3.3.2.iso
```

---

Line 433 is as follows:

> "$app_java_home/bin/java"
>   -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname"
>   -Dexe4j.totalDataLength=73387877 -Dinstall4j.cwd="$old_pwd" -Djava.ext.dirs="$app_java_home/lib/ext"
>   "-Dinstall4j.nolaf=true"
>   "-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true" "$vmov_1"
>   "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4"
>   "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS
>   -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.Launcher launch
>   com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer
>   false false "" "" false true false ""
>   true true 0 0 "" 20 20 "Arial" "0,0,0"
>   8 500 "version 10.0" 20 40 "Arial"
>   "0,0,0" 8 500 -1  "$@"

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of `/tmp/setupLinux64.sh.28603.dir/jre/bin/java`?

Comment: This should probably be on serverfault. Lots of systems don't let you execute files from /tmp (http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch4.en.html#s4.9)

Comment: Hi Dennis - no, there isnt any file/folder like that created... (see edit for more details)

Comment: Hi dave1010 - I tried from another folder as well. Do you recommend a folder in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your efforts to help. The issue was because of cPanel which was present on the server and preventing execution/creation of files in /tmp

From the help desk of the dedicated hosting provider:

> "The installer has unpacked the install files in /tmp and is trying to run the install from there. cPanel is installed on that server, and one of the things it does is lock tmp so executables can't run from there (mount with noexec option). It's an additional security precaution  to prevent someone from uploading a rootkit through an insecure website script."